# Spring Boot war giving exception in external tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, war

I have developed a spring boot application in STS ide and i was able to run with the main class without any exception.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Java3Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Java3Application.class, args);

    }
}

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        setRegisterErrorPageFilter(false);  
        return application.sources(Java3Application.class);
    }
}
```

I generated the war of the same project using the below plugin and packaging :

```
<packaging>war</packaging>

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Also have a dependency like this,

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

But the generated war is giving null pointer exception when one of my rest controllers are getting hit, but same is working fine with Main class.
What is happening in my case?? Is my war packaging is wrong or in sufficient??

Answer (score 1):

To make a spring boot application run in external tomcat, you have to extend it to SpringBootServletInitializer. Modify your code as below

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Java3Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Java3Application.class, args);

    }
}
```

Comment: In that case it doesn't seems to be a config issue. are you seeing null pointer in any one specific API or all APIs are throwing NPE?

Comment: I only have two rest controllers, HttpAdapter and HttpNoRespAdapter, which is getting hit from a another application.

Comment: It would be tough to root cause based on this information. can you provide your controller class, pom.xml etc

Comment: okay, I am providing the link for pom.xml https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vPfo_MLtdU7cxEVsu_Kh6PKlNdCVxGFgW8Xgr1egf8U/edit?usp=sharing